# Is there a way in pyQGIS to change parameter inputs based on what the user selects in other parameters?

Tags: pyqgis, choice-list

Say I have a number of inputs in a python script. If a user selects a certain value in an input then the other inputs can change/disable/new parameters pop up that where hidden, ect.

Is there anything in the def initAlgorithm(self, config=None): where this can be done?

I know in ESRI's arcpy script tool creation, there was a class that would run every time a user would select a certain value in a parameter. ToolValidator class, or the UpdateParameters method

Comment: Correct. Is there anything equivalent like that in QGIS?